# multiple text fields using same ID - html hidden fields

Tags: html, forms

I kinda get confused with using IDs. Can I use this code to add a hidden field?  Where I'm using the same ID for the hidden field that I use in the "course" text field?

```
<div class="form-item left">
  <label for="course"><span class="req">*</span>Course</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" id="course" name="course" />
    <input type="hidden" id="course" name="school" value="Contacted from Student 
 sign-up  page" />
</div>
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique in an HTML document. [You should only use an ID once](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute).

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID).

If you want to build some "connection" between the fields, consider using [`class`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#classes) or a [`data-` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Comment: Use class. Marking multiple elements as part of an arbitrary group is what it is designed for (and since it takes a space separated list of values you can't claim it is being used for something else already).

Comment: @Quentin I agree that in most cases `class` is the right one to use.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, yes i want to build a connection between fields, so would using the data- attribute look something like this?`<div class="form-item left">
  <label for="course"><span class="req">*</span>Course</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" id="course" name="course" />
    <input type="hidden" data-id="course" name="school" value="Contacted from Student 
 sign-up  page" />
</div>
`

Comment: @raydev Seems to be a valid example. Remember that your code is responsible for building the actual connection, `data-` attributes do not do anything by default (only provide additional data).

Comment: or should i add a class attribute like this: `<input type="text" class="text course" id="course" name="course" /> <input type="hidden" class="course" name="school" value="Contacted from Student sign-up page" /> ...`

Comment: FYI:  I didn't create this form or fields, was just asked to add hidden fields so that the instructors will know what page the contact came from.  i'm only doing the HTML, no server coding...

Comment: thanks, Quentin. I had to read your comment twice to get what you are saying.  ID unique, class reusable...